# Depicting incidence density in R

Tags: r

In epidemiology, incidence density is the number of events typically divided by person-time. For example, if 5 people are followed for 1 year each, each one of them contributes one person-year to the experiment. If 2 events happened, your incidence density would be 2 events divided by 5 person-years, or 0.4 events per person-year. This sort of estimate is particularly useful when you have a study of subjects with different follow-up times, where each one of them contributes to the total amount of person-time.

I am looking for the best way to generate these data in an R notebook workflow without having to do calculations by hand as the database is updated over time.

So, I have a dataframe with MRNs, infection yes/no coded as 1/0, person-time contributed (dbl), and a categorical grouping variable, in this toy example let's call it sex male/female coded as 1/0. Again, incidence density is going to be the total number of infections (infection == 1) divided by person-time.

Toy data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
MRN <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
person_time <- c(10, 55, 6, 8, 100)
infection_yn <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
sex <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)

df <- tibble(MRN, person_time, infection_yn, sex)
print(df)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
    MRN person_time infection_yn     sex
  <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1          10            1        1
2     2          55            0        1
3     3           6            1        1
4     4           8            1        0
5     5         100            0        0
```

I want to generate a table with incidence density subsetted by the categorical variable sex. It would ideally produce this table:

```r
sex <- c(1, 0)
incidence_density <- c(0.03, 0.009)

df2 <- tibble(sex, incidence_density)
print(df2)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
    sex    incidence_density
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 0.03 
2     0 0.009
```

How would you approach this problem? All I can figure out is a very crude calculation step by step using filter() + sum() and count() to get person-years and infections and then doing the division myself, but there has got to be a better way. Happy to explain further. Help appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the exact output you expect from the input data

Comment: Thank you - I may be misunderstanding your question, but what I want is the output shown above in df2. From the data in df1, you can calculate an incidence density for each level of sex which is depicted in df2. I don't necessarily need a second data frame per se, just the data in a way such that as the input is updated the output is updated automatically. Because it was confusing, I will update df2 to have the actual correct numbers as calculated from df1.

Comment: I just wanted to crosscheck the output.  Please check the solution posted beelow

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but using mean(infection_yn/person_time) doesn't produce the correct incidence density which is calculated by the absolute number of infections divided by summed person_time.

Comment: If you could update the correect values, I can crosschcek

Comment: yes I've updated them - I should have done this from the beginning. df2 contains the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could group by 'sex', get the `sum` of 'infection_yn', and 'person_time' and divide

```
df %>%     
    group_by(sex)  %>%
    summarise(incidence_density = sum(infection_yn)/sum(person_time))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#    sex incidence_density
#  <dbl>             <dbl>
#1     0           0.00926
#2     1           0.0282
```